# method called mergeNumbers

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, merge

```
    package com.company;

    class mergeNumbers {

    public static void mergeNumbers(int[][] grid, int row, int column, int  nextNumber) {
        grid = new int[][]{
                {2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 8},
                {2, 1, 0, 2, 4, 0},
                {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3},
                {2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0},
                {0, 0, 5, 8, 7, 2},
                {2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}};
        }
    }
```

//A Cell of the board is either empty or contains a number.

Comment: What is your question? One issue with your code, you can't modify the caller's reference to `grid`.

Comment: //A Cell of the board is either empty or contains a number.
// method “mergeNumbers” should first check if grid[row][column] is zero,
// if not then it should return immediately.
// If the grid[row][column] is zero, then you should assign the next
// number to grid[row][column],in essence grid[row][column]= nextNumber;
//If you call mergeNumbers(grid, 3, 3, 1)
// you need to start merging all 1’s which are reachable from cell (3,3)
// three one’s will be merged to two which will be located (row, column)
//Now grid[3][3] contains 2 instead of 1.

Comment: That is your assignment; not a question.

Comment: //There are still some numbers that can be merged at (3,3)
//You need merge these two’s at (3,3)again
// done since there are no possible merging left.
//
// For instance, in the above example if you call
// mergeNumbers (grid, 0, 4, 4) (4 will be place at row=0 and column=4)
// there will be two neighboring 4’s.
// But since there only two cells containing the same number then you should not merge.

Comment: and I am asking for help

Comment: you cannot change `grid` reference outside by using `new int[][]{...}` inside the method

Comment: @triana, Update the question along with your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] puma = {{1, 2, 0, 3}, {3, 2, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 4, 2}, {3, 3, 0, 4}};
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter space for putting 1: ");
    int a = input.nextInt();
    int b = input.nextInt();


    if (a == 0 && b == 2) {
        puma[0][2] = 1;
        for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
            for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

            }
            System.out.print('\n');
        }

        System.out.println("Enter space for putting 2: ");
        a = input.nextInt();
        b = input.nextInt();


        if (a == 1 && b == 2) {
            puma[1][2] = 2;
            for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                    System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                }
                System.out.print('\n');
            }

            System.out.println("Enter space for putting 3: ");
            a = input.nextInt();
            b = input.nextInt();


            if (a == 2 && b == 0) {
                puma[2][0] = 3;
                for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                    for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                        System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                    }
                    System.out.print('\n');
                }

                System.out.println("Enter space for putting 1: ");
                a = input.nextInt();
                b = input.nextInt();


                if (a == 2 && b == 1) {
                    puma[2][1] = 1;
                    for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                        for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                            System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                        }
                        System.out.print('\n');
                    }

                    System.out.println("Enter space for putting 2: ");
                    a = input.nextInt();
                    b = input.nextInt();

                    if (a == 3 && b == 2) {
                        puma[3][2] = 2;
                        for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                            for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                                System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                            }
                            System.out.print('\n');

                        }

                    }


                    if (a == 3 && b == 2) {
                        puma[3][2] = 1;
                        for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                            for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                                System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                            }
                            System.out.print('\n');
                        }

                        System.out.println("Enter space for putting 2: ");
                        a = input.nextInt();
                        b = input.nextInt();

                        if (a == 2 && b == 1) {
                            puma[2][1] = 2;
                            for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                                for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                                    System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                                }
                                System.out.print('\n');
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }



                if (a == 2 && b == 1) {
                    puma[2][1] = 3;
                    for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                        for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                            System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                        }
                        System.out.print('\n');
                    }
                    System.out.println("Enter space for putting 1: ");
                    a = input.nextInt();
                    b = input.nextInt();

                    if (a == 2 && b == 0) {
                        puma[2][0] = 1;
                        for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                            for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                                System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                            }
                            System.out.print('\n');
                        }
                        System.out.println("Enter space for putting 2: ");
                        a = input.nextInt();
                        b = input.nextInt();

                        if (a == 3 && b == 2) {
                            puma[3][2] = 2;
                        }

                    }

                    if (a == 3 && b == 2) {
                        puma[3][2] = 1;
                        for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                            for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                                System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                            }
                            System.out.print('\n');
                        }
                        System.out.println("Enter space for putting 2: ");
                        a = input.nextInt();
                        b = input.nextInt();

                        if (a == 2 && b == 0) {
                            puma[2][0] = 2;
                        }
                    }
                }



                if (a == 3 && b == 2) {
                    puma[3][2] = 3;
                    for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                        for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                            System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                        }
                        System.out.print('\n');
                    }
                    System.out.println("Enter space for putting 1: ");
                    a = input.nextInt();
                    b = input.nextInt();
                }


            }

            if (a == 2 && b == 0) {
                puma[2][0] = 2;
                for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                    for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                        System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                    }
                    System.out.print('\n');
                }
                System.out.println("Enter space for putting 3: ");
                a = input.nextInt();
                b = input.nextInt();

                if (a == 1 && b == 2) {
                    puma[1][2] = 3;
                }

                if (a == 2 && b == 1) {
                    puma[2][1] = 3;
                }

                if (a == 3 && b == 2) {
                    puma[3][2] = 3;
                }
            }



            if (a == 2 && b == 1) {
                puma[2][1] = 2;
                for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                    for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                        System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                    }
                    System.out.print('\n');
                }
                System.out.println("Enter space for putting 3: ");
                a = input.nextInt();
                b = input.nextInt();

                if (a == 1 && b == 2) {
                    puma[1][2] = 3;
                }
                if (a == 2 && b == 0) {
                    puma[2][0] = 3;
                }
                if (a == 3 && b == 2) {
                    puma[3][2] = 3;
                }
            }

            if (a == 3 && b == 2) {
                puma[3][2] = 2;
                for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                    for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                        System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                    }
                    System.out.print('\n');
                }
                System.out.println("Enter space for putting 3: ");
                a = input.nextInt();
                b = input.nextInt();

                if (a == 1 && b == 2) {
                    puma[1][2] = 3;
                }

                if (a == 2 && b == 0) {
                    puma[2][0] = 3;
                }
                if (a == 2 && b == 1) {
                    puma[2][1] = 3;
                }
            }

        }



        if (a == 1 && b == 2) {
            puma[1][2] = 1;
            for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                    System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                }
                System.out.print('\n');
            }
            System.out.println("Enter space for putting 2: ");
            a = input.nextInt();
            b = input.nextInt();
        }



        if (a == 2 && b == 0) {
            puma[2][0] = 1;
            for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                    System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                }
                System.out.print('\n');
            }
            System.out.println("Enter space for putting 2: ");
            a = input.nextInt();
            b = input.nextInt();
        }



        if (a == 2 && b == 1) {
            puma[2][1] = 1;
            for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                    System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                }
                System.out.print('\n');
            }
            System.out.println("Enter space for putting 2: ");
            a = input.nextInt();
            b = input.nextInt();
        }



        if (a == 3 && b == 2) {
            puma[3][2] = 1;
            for (a = 0; a < puma.length; a++) {
                for (b = 0; b < puma[0].length; b++) {
                    System.out.print(puma[a][b] + " ");

                }
                System.out.print('\n');
            }
            System.out.println("Enter space for putting 2: ");
            a = input.nextInt();
            b = input.nextInt();
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < puma.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < puma[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(puma[i][j] + " ");

            }
            System.out.print('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

}

//this is what ı can after with looong trying to do it in short way :(

Comment: Are you intending this to be an answer?  Or is this more evidence as to what you've managed to do?  If it's the latter, please edit it into your question.